# Getting rows with count > 1 without executing two different queries

Tags: sql, filter, count, teradata

I have a table that looks like this:

| ITE_ITEM_ID | SIT_SITE_ID | INVENTORY_ID | ITE_VARIATION_ID | STOCK_EAN | STOCK_FULFILLMENT_ACTIVE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16302514 | B | WAE6496 | 62101793519 | 79098642 | 1 |
| 6210113 | M | GKVU072 | [object Object] | NULL | 1 |
| 16021657 | M | YHQG635 | 60513515602 | NULL | 1 |
| 8449326 | A | ZZRV751 | 52555136800 | NULL | 1 |
| 1154338160 | B | VXWP565 | NULL | NULL | 0 |
| 559568 | M | GYPZ201 | 32325593678 | NULL | 1 |
| 13255753 | B | PH63355 | 70388916917 | NULL | 1 |
| 7614543 | M | XOQO412 | 51698700618 | NULL | 1 |

I am trying to get the different `ITE_VARIATION_ID` that share the same `STOCK_EAN` and have a count > 1

I am currently doing this by splitting two statements:

```
create multiset volatile table eans_plus as (
SELECT STOCK_EAN, count(*) as count_ean
FROM my_table
group by 1
having count_ean > 1
) with data primary index (stock_ean) on commit preserve rows;

SELECT a.STOCK_EAN, a.ITE_VARIATION_ID
from my_table a inner join eans_plus b on a.stock_ean = b.stock_ean
;
```

however this takes a while to execute (>140 secs), since the table is very large, I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this, either by avoiding executing two queriees or adding an index. I am using alation on Teradata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine into a single query easily enough, but the performance improvement from doing that is likely to be quite small:

```
WITH eans_plus AS (
SELECT STOCK_EAN, count(*) as count_ean
FROM my_table
WHERE STOCK_EAN IS NOT NULL
group by 1
having count_ean > 1
)
SELECT a.STOCK_EAN, a.ITE_VARIATION_ID
from my_table a inner join eans_plus b on a.stock_ean = b.stock_ean
;
```

You could also use a window function with QUALIFY; not sure this would be an improvement

```
SELECT STOCK_EAN, ITE_VARIATION_ID
FROM my_table a
WHERE STOCK_EAN IS NOT NULL
QUALIFY COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY STOCK_EAN) > 1;
```

Making `STOCK_EAN` the Primary Index for `my_table` (if it isn't already) could improve these queries, but you'd need to see how it impacts distribution and other usage of this table.

A single-table join index would likely improve performance for these queries, though table maintenance would see some performance degradation.

```
CREATE JOIN INDEX my_table_aji AS
SELECT STOCK_EAN, COUNT(*) as theCount FROM my_table
GROUP BY 1
PRIMARY INDEX (STOCK_EAN);
```

EDIT: add `WHERE STOCK_EAN IS NOT NULL` filtering

Comment: Thanks Fred. Question: these tables are actually views (I have read-only access, and I am interested only in retrieving data). Do Join Index tables work as volatile tables?

Comment: You can't define a Join Index on a Volatile table or a View, only on underlying tables. I agree with @Gordon that based on your sample data, filtering out `NULL` values would likely help performance. I have edited my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to get the different ITE_VARIATION_ID that share the same STOCK_EAN and have a count > 1

This sounds like an aggregation query to me:

```
select STOCK_EAN, ITE_VARIATION_ID, COUNT(*)
from t
where stock_ean is not null
group by STOCK_EAN, ITE_VARIATION_ID
qualify sum(count(*)) over (partition by stock_ean) > 1;
```

Filtering the `NULL` values may help performance.